# PrestaShop add to cart from custom module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I ma working on PrestaShop module, where the user can select some parameters on front view.

I need to add product to cart, including custom price, and selected parameters.

How should I do this? I don't want to override deafult behavior, as not all products will use my component.

Any help would be awesome.
Have a nice day, Bartek.

Comment: check how PS default doit in frontend: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/544762-custom-add-to-cart-button/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a product to a cart is pretty simple :

First create an empty cart :

```
$cart=new Cart();
... here you can set your cart properties id_address / id_carrier etc...
$cart->add();
```

Or, if you already have a cart to use just load the Cart object with its ID and perform :

```
$cart->updateQty($quantity, $id_product, $id_product_attribute, false);
$cart->update();
```

You should repeate the **updateQty()** method for each product / qties you'd need to add to the cart.

In order to customize product prices in cart you have to create product "specific prices" using the **SpecificPrice** object and bind them to that **id_cart** :

```
$mySpecificPrice = new SpecificPrice();
$mySpecificPrice->id_cart = $cart->id;
... add your discount / id_product here on specific price here ...
$mySpecificPrice->add();
```

Note that you can only set price discounts with **SpecificPrice** , surcharges are not allowed and will trigger an exeception.

If you need to increase your prices without any core modification, you'll forced to generate an **Order** and edit the order prices afterward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Seems logical! Is there any chance to reach out to you, and ask some questions about my needs?